# Incorrect type inference for Rust vector of trait object

Tags: rust, trait-objects

I am having trouble understanding the following error:

```
// test.rs

struct A {
    a: u32
}

trait B { }

impl B for A { }

struct C {
    c: Vec<Box<dyn B>>,
}

fn test() {
    let a = A {a: 1};
    let a_vec = vec![Box::new(a)];
    let c = C {
        c: a_vec,
        // c: vec![Box::new(a)],
    };
}
```

Compile error:

```
mismatched types

expected trait object `dyn test::B`, found struct `test::A`
```

The error occurs on the line where I try to create C. What's interesting is that if I create C in the following way then it compiles alright.

```
let c = C {
        c: vec![Box::new(a)],
    };
```

Another way that would work is

```
let a_vec: Vec<Box<dyn B>> = vec![Box::new(a)];
let c = C {
        c: a_vec,
    };
```

One other experiment I did is to change the type of C.c to just Box instead of Vec<Box>, and then it compiles no matter how I initiate it.

Seems to me this might be some missing feature/bug of Rust's type inference regarding vector of trait objects? I am still very new to Rust so any idea on this is really appreciated!

Comment: Another variant that works is `vec![Box::new(a) as _]`. The error itself is due to the difference between the thin pointer (boxed concrete struct) and a fat pointer (boxed dyn trait). One is convertible to the other (provided the struct implements the trait), but sometimes the compiler needs some nudging to perform the conversion. Whether that's a deficiency in the type inference or a consequence of some deeper principle is a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all expected behaviour. A `Box<A>` can be coerced into a `Box<dyn B>` – this is called an [*unsized coercion*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#unsized-coercions), and it happens implicitly whenever the compiler knows that the target type is `Box<dyn B>`. However, when just writing

```
let a_vec = vec![Box::new(a)];
```

the compiler doesn't know the item type of the vector, so it infers it from the expression on the right-hand side, meaning that `a_vec` ends up with the type `Vec<Box<A>>`.

There is no unsized coercion from `Vec<Box<A>>` to `Vec<Box<dyn B>>`. Converting `Box<A>` to `Box<dyn B>` simply means converting a pointer to a fat pointer on the stack, which is a cheap operation. Converting vectors of these elements is very different – it would require reallocating the whole vector and unsizing each element, which is a rather expensive operation, so it should never happen implicitly.

In all the versions that actually compile, the vector is created as a `Vec<Box<dyn B>>` right from the get-go, since you tell the compiler that's the type you want.

Comment: *This is all expected behaviour* - The part I wouldn't expect is for `vec![Box::new(a)]` to not work, but for `vec![Box::new(a) as _]` to work. The `as _` appears redundant - what new information is it giving the compiler that it couldn't infer without it?

Comment: @user4815162342 It's actually giving the compiler _less_ information in a sense. The compiler tries to infer the type of `a_vec` based on the right-hand side. If the right-hand side is `vec![Box::new(a)]`, the compiler can infer a complete type, `Vec<Box<A>>`, since that's the type of the expression. If you add `as _`, the compiler can't infer a complete type anymore, and only infers `Vec<_>`. The initialization of `c` then gives the compiler further hints that `_` is actually `Box<dyn B>`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to understand why the compiler infers the complete type of the vector for `let a_vec = vec![Box::new(a); /* use a_vec where Vec<Box<dyn T>> is expected */`, but not in `let c = C { c: vec![Box::new(a)] }`. I would expect if the former fails to compile due to type mismatch, then that so does the latter. Or, in other words, if the compiler were changed for the OP's code to compile, would that cause issues in some cases?

Comment: @user4815162342 In `let c = C { c: vec![Box::new(a)] }`, there is no type to infer. The type of the `c` field of the struct `C` is already known.